# Is it okay to ask how to find certain labs on physics stack exchange?

Tags: discussion

I am currently trying to find labs and groups that are exploring a certain topic. The background is that I'm trying to apply to grad school and looking for labs that are suitable for my interest. The problem is that since I'm fairly new to physics research, I'm having difficulty phrasing my questions specifically enough to find what I'm looking for. I was wondering if it's appropriate to enquire about this on physics stack exchange or if it's not? I'd be asking things akin to "how do I find labs that are approaching this question?", "what are better ways to phrase this [conceptual question] as a research question?", and "how to find labs who are researching [insert]?"?

Comment: Chat might be a good place, but those questions don't seem appropriate on the main page.

Comment: Options: (1) talk to your professors, (2) look at conference programs (say https://meetings.aps.org/Meeting/MAR22/APS_epitome#Monday and other days) and see what talks in related areas are given, (3) peruse PRL or APL or other possible journals.

Comment: Related: *[Are resource recommendations allowed?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4697/are-resource-recommendations-allowed)* and *[Is it relevant to ask questions regarding careers in physics and not actually some physics concept?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7523/is-it-relevant-to-ask-questions-regarding-careers-in-physics-and-not-actually-so)*

Answer (score 7):

What you have in mind doesn’t seem to be about physics as a science, answerable by a principle from physics or a closely related field, but rather about research groups in physics.  The latter types of questions are usually off-topics on the main site.